Jquery 4.0 data.hasOwnProperty is not a function
I am using the cycle slider and it creates using jquery 4.0 the following error.  data.hasOwnProperty is not a function on this piece of code. Can you please advice how to fix this issue?  Thank you
    return this.each(function() {
    var data, opts, shortName, val;
    var container = $(this);
    var log = $.fn.cycle2.log;

    if ( container.data('cycle2.opts') )
        return; // already initialized

    if ( container.data('cycle2-log') === false || 
        ( options && options.log === false ) ||
        ( opts && opts.log === false) ) {
        log = $.noop;
    }

    log('--c2 init--');
    data = container.data();
    for (var p in data) {
        // allow props to be accessed sans 'cycle2' prefix and log the overrides
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(p) && /^cycle2[A-Z]+/.test(p) ) {
            val = data[p];
            shortName = p.match(/^cycle2(.*)/)[1].replace(/^[A-Z]/, lowerCase);
            log(shortName+':', val, '('+typeof val +')');
            data[shortName] = val;
        }
    }

    opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.cycle2.defaults, data, options || {});

